# Refactoring a function definition

Tags: python, eclipse, refactoring, pydev

I am using Pydev on Eclipse to write python code. I am new to Pydev and to Eclipse. I love the feature where by I can use rightClick -> Refactoring -> Rename... to rename a variable.

I was wondering if there is something similar to change a function everywhere in the project, if I change its definition.

For example, suppose I initially have:

```
def myFunction(a, b):
    body of the function
    return blah
```

I use this function in other files of the project. Say,

```
thisVar = myFunction(a, b)
```

Now I feel the need to change the function definition to account for an additional parameter.

```
def myFunction(a, b, c):
    body of the function
    return blah
```

Is there something in eclipse or pydev such that it will automatically change

```
thisVar = myFunction(a, b)
```

to

```
thisVar = myFunction(a, b, c)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've never used Eclipse nor pydev (I use basic text editors) but if you just want to change the `myFunc(a, b)` to `myFunc(a, b, c)` can't you do a find and replace?

Comment: @vlad That's what PyDev's refactor does: it does a search and replace. I don't recommend you use this feature: it changes the words in comments, strings...

Comment: If PyDev offers the inline method refactoring, then you could have myFunction(a, b) call myNewFunction(a, b, c), then inline myFunction, then rename myNewFunction.  More steps than you might want to go through, and given Beau's response, I suspect it's unlikely to work reliably, if it's available.  But it might be a usable approach.

Answer (score 2):

no IDE may support this as when you call a function it requires variable which may not be the `c` all the time,

what I suggest is keep the parameter c as optional like

```
thisVar = myFunction(a, b, c = None)
```

and when you actually realize that it requires c then you can call those statements by using 3 parameters or `myFunction(10,20, c = 2000)`

Comment: +1 In fact, it's rather unlikely that there is a `c` at call side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think refactoring methods exist in Pydev of Eclipse. For reasons to why, please see here for reference... it has to do with the construct of python variables

[why doesn't eclipse-python have magic refactor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995842/why-doesnt-eclipse-python-have-magic-refactor)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 4 years old, but Eclipse for java can refactor method definitions and change arguments.  As far as I know, Pydev doesn't include support for python's functions