# why doesn't eclipse-python have magic refactor?

Tags: javascript, python, eclipse, refactoring, automated-refactoring

Eclipse is able to utilize compiled bytecode to enable "magic refactor" functionality--renaming methods, tracing up and down class hierarchies and tracing through method calls.

What technical barriers exist that make this harder to do for languages like Python and Javascript?

Comment: ctrl-H Find and replace *does* work, although you need to be careful...

Comment: PyDev even offers a "renamed this" command that doesn't kill strings and the like. But in general, *static* code analysis can only give limited knowledge about code in a *dynamic* language.

Comment: Eric4 IDE includes refactoring by using the Rope library (http://rope.sourceforge.net/). I haven't used it too extensively but it seems to do a nice job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it turns out that tracing of static information like methods and class hierarchies is perfectly possible in python. PyDev eclipse plugin does it. PyLint plugin attempts to do static analysis even on stuff like dynamic variables by assuming that nothing funky happens at runtime and does a pretty good job.

Comment: It would be nice if you would provide the explanation how exactly do you achieve what you're stating. Otherwise, this "self"-answer is not full. I'd appreciate to  know for example how can i automatically fix imports in my project after i moved python modules int subpackages. That's one thing that java refactoring does easily, but i'm failing to do that for python. Thanks!

Comment: In 2015 and PyDev 3.9.0.20141111, such refactoring capacity is still missing (for whatever reason--this comment isn't about that). What I've found the most effective substitute is  find . -name '*.py' -exec sed -i 's/search/replace/g'  and being really careful about what I'm doing.

Answer (score 6):

Because of dynamic binding. Python is a dynamic language in a way that you can do almost everything with your variables. You can even access the globals-dict and introduce new variables composed of runtime values.

So an IDE can’t be sure which variables exist when. See this example:

```
#silly.py

import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    thisNowExists = True

#1

try:
    if thisNowExists:
        print("this existed before")
except NameError:
    print("this _now_ exists")
    thisNowExists = True
```

No human or IDE can know if `thisNowExists` is defined at the position `#1`, so if you want to rename the stupidly named `thisNowExists` below that point, it is undefined if we should rename the appearance before `#1`, too.

You would have to do advanced control flow analysis to take a good guess that `thisNowExists` is defined below the try/catch statement, but due to dynamic loading of the script (`thisNowExists = 1; import silly`) and sorts, it could even exist before `import sys` without arguments.

naming your variables differently and find/replace is your best option ;)

Comment: i am much more interested in tracing through methods and class hierarchies, does that change anything?

Comment: could you please explain what you mean by that comment? i’m no native speaker and i just don’t get it, sorry.